# c# connecting to mssql from client

Tags: sql-server, winforms, client

I wrote a simple application using windows forms. It works without problem on pc where mssql is installed. On client in first form Im logging in getting data from mssql with no problem. When next form should appear Im receiving

```
The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication”
```

My connection string is

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Password=!;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Data Source=SERVER\SQL");
```

and it works on first form. I dont understand why He recognizes this connection as Windows authenticaton...

Comment: I found solution, Problem was with global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute in settings.designer